# Sorting single-bucket aggregation by a stats aggregated scripted field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to sort a multi-bucket aggregation by a stats-aggregated scripted field within a particular bucket. Since aggregations can't be sorted by multi-bucket aggregator values, I added a single-bucket aggregation with the required bucket. However, sorting by the single bucket's sub-aggregation field still throws an error.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "purchase_time": {
              "from": 1686096000000,
              "to": 1686700799999
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "customer_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer_id",
        "size": 50,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "order": [
          {
            "sortByAggregation.cost_aggregation.sum": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "category": {
          "filters": {
            "filters": {
              "Dairy": {
                "terms": {
                  "category": [
                    "Dairy"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "Fruit": {
                "terms": {
                  "category": [
                    "Fruit"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "Chocolates": {
                "terms": {
                  "category": [
                    "Chocolates"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "Groceries": {
                "terms": {
                  "category": [
                    "Dairy",
                    "Fruit"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "other_bucket": false,
            "other_bucket_key": "_other_"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "indiv_statsAgg": {
              "stats": {
                "script": {
                  "id": "purchase-cost-adjusted"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "sortByAggregation": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "category": [
                "Dairy"
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "cost_aggregation": {
              "sum": {
                "script": {
                  "id": "purchase-cost-adjusted"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On running this query, am facing error **"Invalid aggregator order path [sortByAggregation.cost_aggregation.sum]. Unknown aggregation [sortByAggregation.cost_aggregation]"**
Why isn't the single-bucket aggregation working as expected?